# Can I fit a general linear model to this kind of data?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, continuous-data

I have one continuous dependent variable, and two independent variables. The first independent variable is categorical (three groups) and the second independent variable is continuous.

The DV is a measure of size, and the IVs are group and age. I am interested in how the group affects size. The age is a possible confounding variable.

Can I use a general linear model to analyze this kind of data? My statistical knowledge is somewhat limited. Without the possible confounder I would just do a standard 1-factor ANOVA.

Comment: Sure it can. Just fit the group factor (via dummies if your software doesn't do it automagically) and age (and interactions if you need to consider the possibility that the group difference also depends on age). However "size" sounds like it is a non-negative variable where conditional variance will be related to conditional mean (and also conditionally skewed) and you might actually be better using a *generalized* linear model.

Comment: Do you mean by "via dummies" that I should code each group separately using binary indicator variables?

Comment: If your software doesn't handle factors automatically, yes - or another suitable coding if you have one. However, you'll need to leave out one level of the total set as the baseline.